# Open new packages homepage in homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

Is there a way to isolate the list of new packages added to homebrew?
When I run brew upgrade it lists all the new packages,
and I want to open their homepage to see if I want to use them.

Something along the lines of

```
$ brew home $(brew list --new)
```

which iterates through all the new packages and opens their homepage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can string a couple commands to do this:

1. List the outdated packages:

   ```
   $ brew outdated
   git (1.8.5.1, 1.9.0, 2.0.0 < 2.2.0)
   ```
2. `brew home` only wants the name, not the versions, so parse that out

   ```
   $  brew outdated |  awk '{print $1}'
   git
   ```
3. Run `brew home`:

   ```
   $ brew home `brew outdated |  awk '{print $1}'`
   OR
   $ brew outdated |  awk '{print $1}' | xargs brew home
   ```
4. Optional: My machine errors out `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712` if I try to open more then 6 urls. Quick googling suggests that it's a timeout, which suggests that your machine and browser may time out after more or less urls.

   ```
   $ for package in `brew outdated |  awk '{print $1}'`; do brew home $package; done
   ```